# Getting multiple "There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing."

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd

I'm developing a frontend with NextJS and Antdesign.

While trying to build a simple login with the Form components provided by AntDesign I'm getting spammed with these errors:

```
./node_modules/antd/es/Button/style/index.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* javascript/auto|/Users/pat/Projects/backend/client/node_modules/antd/es/Button/style/index.js|sc_client
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|/Users/pat/Projects/backend-/client/node_modules/antd/es/Button/button.js|sc_client
* javascript/auto|/Users/pat/Projects/backend-/client/node_modules/antd/es/button/style/index.js|sc_client
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.    javascript/auto|/Users/pat/Projects/backend-/client/node_modules/antd/es/button/button.js|sc_client

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/antd/es/Button/style/index.js
./node_modules/antd/es/Button/button.js
./node_modules/antd/es/Button/index.js
./src/components/navbar/navbar.tsx
```

When removing the form components no errors shown in the console, why is this happening and can I do something about it?

Comment: Try using more descriptive names like HappyButton or *Appname*SubmitButton ?  Using generic names for objects and functions makes name collisions / clashes much more likely.  Don't use Button1, 2, 3... either because then you will forget what each button does when you look at the code later.

Comment: @DaveS These are from the Antdesign components package, I can't change the name of the Buttons, or is it something I'm missing here?

Comment: Are those your only Button objects?  If you are including anything else or have other custom code that other thing might have used its own generic names.  You can use a file search tool (a grep type tool) to search the rest of your code.

Comment: @DaveS That's the only Button components, I have not created any custom Button components. That's why it's so weird, is this a bug between NextJS and Antdesign?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. It was a bug with NextJS 13.4.8, downgrading to 13.4.7 solved it.

Answer (score 0):

In my function component, I imported Link as below：

```
import Link from "next/Link";
```

But, the right way is：

```
import Link from "next/link";
```